# What are the specific risks from Developer Mode on iOS?

Tags: ios, security

Because iOS simulator no longer supports BLE (I think), I sometimes need to test my internal distribution app (using Expo development server) on a hardware device. But since iOS 16, in order to do this, it is necessary to enable "Developer Mode" on the device. According to the setting's instructions this results in "reduced" security.

Exactly what risks do I expose myself to when I turn on "Developer Mode" on my iOS (16+) device?

Comment: The simulator hasn't supported BLE since somewhere around ios 4. There are no additional security risks in iOS 16 developer mode than there were previously. Apple just wants you to be aware. The risk is that developer mode allows you to install apps that are not reviewed or signed by apple. It also enables other debugging features, available under developer settings that may modify the way the device behaves or provide access to data that would not otherwise be accessible

Comment: @Paulw11 That's the question what are the _specific_ risks of Developer Mode (generally, not whether they're different on 16). Who and under what circumstances can they be exploited.

Comment: The primary risk is untrusted code execution, still within a sandbox, but untrusted/Unreviewed could exploit some vulnerability to escape the sandbox. The risks can be exploited by anyone who has physical access to your phone and knows your passcode

Comment: Just so you know, you have always had to enable developer mode, Xcode just did it for you when you connected your phone and used the "trust" process. They have just made it more explicit in ios16

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah that’s interesting. But only on a per source basis (the trusted machine) and without having to reboot, right? That’s a big difference.

Comment: The only change is the need to reboot.

Comment: @Paulw11 So trusting the source device used to enable Developer Mode for any device?

Comment: Yep. Once you connected the device to Xcode and went through the trust process you would see a "developer"menu in settings. This was disabled on reboot until you reconnected to Xcode but you didn't need to repeat the trust

Comment: @Paulw11 And if I then plugged the same phone into a completely different Mac, I could install an app from that Mac without having to confirm "trust" again?

Comment: No. You would need to trust that Mac with the device passcode

Comment: @Paulw11 So what you send above is wrong, or it wasn't clear what I was asking (in the comments): there is now a change in how this is enabled. It s now enabled (on the iOS device) globally for that device rather than on a per source  basis (by "trusting" on connection to each source). Correct? That's a very big change. But I digress — the question remains (and is not about the change, despite these comments): what are the risks of being in Developer Mode? Exactly what can no be done tom iOS device that could not have been done before.

Comment: No, you still need an individual trust, you just can't even start that trust process until developer mode is enabled. iOS 16 is more restricted, not less. iOS 16 developer mode must also remain enabled to run adhoc builds (ie builds "sideloaded" through drag and drop)

Comment: @Paulw11 It sounds like you understand this pretty fully. It would be great to have it all spelled out in a single answer, rather than cheese-shopped here in comments.

Comment: I think the old trust process was nothing tod do with a developer mode. For one thing, it was triggered by iTunes just as much as XCode.

Comment: @O'Rooney it would be great to have this simple question cleared up. So far it's been Cheese-shopped to the point that I'm not sure any of the above is relevant or useful (or true).

Comment: Especially since the device is restarted to enable developer mode, it must do something pretty major. It can't just be a switch for "do we allow ad-hoc provisioning".

Comment: Unless someone jailbreaks his device and compare the behavior between the reboot process, all the answers are not convincing enough. Possible reason that a reboot is required, may be due to stop some and start some other services, changing access level to some files, and so on, but without proof no one really knows what happens, and what exactly makes the device less secured.